# Which screen resolution is valid?

Tags: resolution

I used the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949844/python-calculate-the-screen-size):

```
from Tkinter import *    
root = Tk()
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
print w
print h
```

I get:

```
1920
1018
```

But when I use the answer of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/270718/get-display-resolution-from-windows-command-line):

> wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth

I get:

```
ScreenHeight             ScreenWidth
1080                     1920
```

And when I run:

```
xdpyinfo  | grep 'dimensions:'
```

I get this:

```
  dimensions:    1920x1018 pixels (508x269 millimeters)
```

The first and last methods give me the same result unlike the second one. Which one could I trust ? I need this precise information in order to use it within a larger program.

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Comment: Hmm, FWIW `wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth` for some reason returns no values on my laptop. Wonder why?

Comment: @Karan you must run it on Windows

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a novice and that's obvious. Like I said, no result here for some reason.

Comment: @Karan      1080 x 1920 is the valid one

Comment: Yes, in your case perhaps it is. That's not what I'm puzzled about though.

Comment: @Karan I do not know. In my case, the CMD command works both on my PC and laptop and even in a Virtual machine